# Underline text in UILabel in monotouch (porting ObjC code)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I would like to underline the text in a UILabel.
I have found following code for ObjC:

```
NSDictionary *underlineAttribute = @{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @1}
myLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Test string" 
                                                     attributes:underlineAttribute];
```

I'm trying to port this to C# but it's not working.
I'm trying the following:

```
var keys = new object[] { "NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName" };
var objects = new object[] { 1 };
NSDictionary underlineAttribute = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(objects, keys);
label.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(@"Test",underlineAttribute);
```

Instead of 1, I also tried "1" and NSUnderlineStyle.Single, but nothing is working

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
label.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString (
    "Test", 
    underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.Single);
```

Comment: Thx, this is working! The second attribute in the constructor is using the format "name: value". Is that a short form of a dictionary for 1 item?

Comment: @Matt: no, there is a ctor with a lot of optional parameters, and that syntax is saying to pass NSUnderlineStyle.Single for the `underlineStyle` parameter (and the default value for the rest of the parameters). Xamarin Studio should show you intellisense where you can see the all the parameters you can pass (this is a helper constructor provided by us, we create the dictionary under the hood for you).

Comment: Thanks Rolf. I saw the constructor, but I didn't knew that I'm not forced to supply all of them. Good to know