# How to bind NSAttributeString (or NSMutableAttributedString)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I want to bind an attributed string to a UILabel using MVVMCross. To bind a regular string I would just do:

```
set.Bind(MyLabel).To(vm => vm.MyString);
```

But I need a string where part of the text will use one color and one font size and another part will use a different color and a different font size. If this was static, no problem, I'd add a label in interface builder and set it "attributed" and then set whatever font options I want on which ever parts of the string I need.

So I thought with Mvvmcross, I'd probably need a converter to turn my source string into an attributed string, so I tried creating a converter from `MvxValueConverter<string,NSMutableAttributedString>` that just does this in its `Convert` method:

```
return new NSMutableAttributedString(value);
```

Eventually I'll actually add some different attributes. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. If I set my binding like this:

```
set.Bind(MyLabel).To(vm => vm.MyString).WithConversion("MyConverter");
```

It appears that MvvmCross just does a `.ToString` on the attributed string and it displays as:

```
Some Text {}
```

Note the `{}` aren't part of the original string.

Is there a way to bind an attributed string in MVVMCross?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call

```
 set.Bind(MyLabel).To(vm => vm.MyString);
```

then you are binding the default property of your UILabel which is the `string` property Text.

You need to bind the AttributedText instead. Try adding something like:

```
    .For(l => l.AttributedText)
```

There are some questions on here about using AttributedText - eg [Underline text in UILabel in monotouch (porting ObjC code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643232/underline-text-in-uilabel-in-monotouch-porting-objc-code)

For more on mvx data-binding see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding

Comment: Thanks Stuart. That did it. And thanks for the link, the API for dealing with attributed strings is kinda confusing.

Comment: Can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77337458/add-action-on-part-of-attributed-text-with-mvvmcross-in-xamarin-c-sharp